# Checking if the object passed in to an Interface param has an additional property

Tags: c#

I have two `User` classes, `User`, and `TenantUser` that implement an `IUser` interface:

```
public interface IUser
{
    int Id           { get; set; }
    string Username  { get; set; }
    string Email     { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName  { get; set; }
}
public class User : IUser
{
    public int Id           { get; set; }
    public string Username  { get; set; }
    public string Email     { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
}
public class TenantUser : IUser
{
    public int Id           { get; set; }
    public int TenantId     { get; set; }
    public string Username  { get; set; }
    public string Email     { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
}
```

The only difference is that `TenantUser` has one extra property: `TenantId`

When I am coding I am doing something like the following:

```
IUser user;

user = getAdminUser("username", "password");

if (user == null) 
{
    user = getTenantUser("username", "password");

    if (user == null) 
        return Unauthorized();
}
```

Then when I proceed with my code I will need to check if `TenantId` is a property on the user object, if it, is get the value. Is this possible?

Comment: Cast to the concrete object ? Otherwise you'll need reflection.

Comment: Hmm, there are two possible concrete objects that it could be, so do I do a try cast on both of them to see which one it is?

Comment: This is where interfaces turn ugly.  It is not an IUser, it is an IUserWithTenantId.  Not really something to compromise on, even though you can.  Consider whether you *really* need an interface for such a basic poco object, abstraction has a non-zero cost.

Comment: @HansPassant can you look at my comments on the post below. Is there anyway I can avoid having to do this knowing my requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `TenantId` to another interface and implement it in the `TenantUser`. Then just try to cast to that interface:

Given:

```
interface ITenant
{
    int TenantId { get; set; }
}

public class TenantUser : IUser, ITenant
{ ... }
```

You can do:

```
if(user is ITenant tenant)
{
     // access tenant.TenantId
}
```

Comment: Selman can you show what my TenantUser class would look like?

Comment: It would look the same, just add ITenant after IUser

Comment: I feel like the fact that I am even in this situation is due to bad coding practice to begin with, let me know what you think. I basically have a Users table in the database and a TenantUsers table in the database (very similar properties except for TenantId). One single login page that submits a username and password to an api. With that username and password I first need to see if they can login as an admin then redirect to admin portal, if not I need to see if they can login as a tenant then redirect to tenant portal. I guess the only way I can avoid this is having one Users table correct?

Comment: @BlakeRivell you should hide all the public members of a class behind an interface so you can deal with the interface that allows polymorphism. you don't need to worry about the concrete type or cast to it. That is why I suggested adding `TenantId` to an interface, it is better design IMHO.

Comment: Alright, I am having trouble accessing the tenantId property once I am in the if statement. Can you update the last codeblock in your answer to show me how? Would i first need to cast to TenantUser?

Comment: Woops didn't realize I would have access to the variable from the if statement. Got it thanks!